# Java library using css selectors to parse XML

Tags: java, android, xml, css-selectors, chainability

Is there a jQuery like JAVA/Android library that uses CSS Selectors to parse the XML ?

Like :

```
String desc = myXML.find("bloc[type=pro]").get(0).attr("description");
```

Chainability is also what I'm looking for, in the same way of jQuery...

I hope this exists !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are some bugs in other Libraries like **Jsoup** and **Jericho** is different from what I was expecting,

I wrote a Class Extending the `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` which parse the XML. I then wrote two other Classes that look like `Element` and `Elements` from Jsoup containing two functions called `find` that handle the CSS3 Selector and `attr` that returns the attribute value.

I'm now cleaning and commenting that code... I'll post the library later for who is interested in.

```
xmlDoc.find("bloc[type=Pro]>act").attr("label");
```

is now possible like in jQuery !

---

Edit !

Here is the link to access the code for who is interested : [Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/javaxmlquery/)

---

Moving to GitHub : https://github.com/ChristopheCVB/JavaXMLQuery

Answer (score 9):

While initially designed as a HTML parser with CSS selector support, [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) works fine for XML documents as well if your sole intent is to *extract* data, not to *manipulate* data.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(xmlString);
String desc = document.select("bloc[type=pro]").get(0).attr("description");
// ...
```

You see, the syntax is almost identical to what you have had in the question.

Comment: When I do : `Elements xmlBlocs = doc.select("bloc");` then `xmlBlocs.get(0).select("place")`, I'm getting **place** from other blocs elements... Why ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Perhaps your XML is malformed or you aren't running the code you think you're running?

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) is what you are looking for.

You example would look like

```
String desc = source.getFirstElement( "type", "pro" ).getAttributeValue( "description" );
```

It's a charm to parse HTML with jericho, so I guess it's even easier for well structured XML.

Answer (score 2):

I use XPath to solve that issue.  XML parsing like JDOM is ok to to the XPath.  Maybe jQuery see how XPath works :p

```
//bloc[@type="pro"][1]/@description
```

Xpath index start from 1, not 0

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

The [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library can do many of the things you are looking for. Although the syntax is a little different, you can:

- **Get view attributes using chained, *jQuery*-style commands, such as:**

  ```
  CharSequence text = $.with(this, R.id.myTextView).attr("text");
  ```
- **Parse XML:**

  ```
  Document dom = $.parseXML(myXMLString);
  ```

If you are a fan of *jQuery*, you will be pleased to see that nearly all of the features it provides are included in *droidQuery*, and although the syntax may differ at times, its major goal is to be as syntactically close to *jQuery* as possible.